# Can I include stored procs when using edmgen.exe?

Tags: linq-to-entities, edmgen

I have a couple of scripts I use to generate my edmx files (using edmgen and [edmgen2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2)).

Is there a way to include stored procs?  Or do I have to use the GUI designer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried yet but you can check out

https://ghulal.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/efgen-exe-a-command-line-tool-for-automatic-generation-of-entity-framework-dll/

Comment: updated link https://sidshome.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/efgen-exe-a-command-line-tool-for-automatic-generation-of-entity-framework-dll/