# SqlEntityConnection (Entity Data Model) TypeProvider

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am using the SqlEntityConnection (Entity Data Model) TypeProvider to connect to a SQL Server database that has a few tables and stored procedures.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.Data"
#r "System.Data.Entity"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders"
#endif

open System.Data
open System.Data.Entity
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

// You can use Server Explorer to build your ConnectionString.
type internal SqlConnection = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionString = @"DataSource=server etc">
let internal db = SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
```

According to the documentation provided by a link in the template file - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229210
"Get the data context, which is an object that contains the database tables as properties and the database stored procedures and functions as methods."
db should have the stored procedures in the database as methods. However, I can only see the tables in the database as properties of db.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is the type of the properties?

Answer (score 4):

I think the documentation is incorrect.  The `SqlEntityConnection` TP uses the tool `edmgen.exe` in the backend to do the actual codegen and heavy lifting, and from what I can tell that tool doesn't support including stored procedures as part of the generated proxy classes.  [Here's another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3290091/1366219) asking about exactly this, sadly no replies.

Running

```
edmgen.exe /mode:FullGeneration /connectionstring:"..." /language:CSharp /p:EdmTest
```

outputs various files, only one of which (the `.ssdl` file) contains any information about the stored procedures present in my DB.

The `SqlDataConnection` TP definitely *does* support stored procedures, in case that's a possible alternative for you.